# Combine ASP.NET MVC and Web API projects using identity

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am new to ASP.NET and I have to create an ASP.NET MVC project using the identity framework for authentication and authorization, but the access to the database (SQL Server) must be done in an independent web service project so I created a Web API project with also identity containing all services of the application that request the database, even the authentication is done by calling the methods of the web API and not those of the ASP.NET MVC project and everything works fine.

So the question is: is it possible to prevent the ASP.NET MVC project from creating an instance of the database and to not automatically call the constructor `ApplicationDbContext()` ?

Or is there any possibility to be redirected to Web API project instead of creating dbcontext in the Identity Model ?

Any help please.

Comment: Are you code-first or database-first with entity-framework?

Comment: I used database first

Answer (score 0):

With ASP.net Core 2.0 Web API's and MVC Controllers can be made in the same controller.

Look at this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) to help.

Comment: Thanks @dev8989 for your proposition but the problem is how to prevent the ASP MVC application to automatically access the database to check user authentication.